# Warning on project's NuGet dependencies without any errors on any specific NuGet package in the list

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a project that has a yellow warning sign on the NuGet section icon under it's dependencies, but when I expand the NuGet list to see all NuGets, I don't see any warning signs on any of the NuGets in the list.

[image]

Can anyone advise what could be making this warning appear?

Comment: I also have this from time to time. I simply close the solution and open it again and the error is gone

Comment: @magicandre1981, in my case it the warning stays. Cleaning and re-building the solution doesn't help as well.

Comment: this new PackageReference Include is sometimes buggy. Try to enable the new [lock feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#enabling-lock-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When NuGet restores PackageReference projects it writes a `project.assets.json` file to the intermediate output directory (by default `obj/`) which contains not only information about packages and files in those packages, but stores restore warnings, so that it's possible to show the user the same warning on no-op restores. I believe that the [.NET Project System](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system) reads this and displays the warnings stored in the file as the symbol you see in Solution Explorer, but I think it should also put the warnings in the Error List.

So, you could check your `obj/project.assets.json` file and see if there are any warnings stored in it. I think they're normally at the end of the file.

Another option is to go to the command line and run `msbuild -t:restore`, or `dotnet restore --verbosity normal` (the dotnet cli defaults to minimal). I'd be surprised if that doesn't show you warnings (assuming there really are warnings), but you could try detailed verbosity, but I expect that would mostly show you MSBuild processing information. If you think that NuGet is incorrectly not showing warnings due to no-op, you can use `dotnet restore --force`, which after taking a quick look at the NuGet targets file appears to be equivilent to `msbuild -t:restore -p:RestoreForce=true`, or just delete the `project.assets.json` file and restore normally.